# Ожидание ответа

Tags: ajax, javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы во время обращения к серверу через ajax, во время ожидания ответа сервера выводился какой-нибудь текст, а после получения ответа этот текст убирался.
Я вообще не представляю, как это можно реализовать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**html:**

```
<div class="preloader">Загружаю...</div>
```

**css:**

```
.preloader {
    display: none;
}
```

**js:**

```
var $preloader = $('.preloader');

$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $preloader.show();
    },
    success: function(){

    },
    complete: function(){
      $preloader.hide();
    }
});
```

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/7t7ws9uo/)

Answer (score 0):

У объекта XMLHttpRequest есть метод `onloadstart()`, который активируется при отправке запроса и есть `onloadend()`, который срабатывает после ответа (правда последний иногда по необъяснимым причинам даёт дуба, поэтому лучше проверять в `onload()`, `onerror()` или `onabort()` - что-то из них точно сработает).
[Читать.](http://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 0):

Я реализовывал так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document)
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#loading").show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
)
```